# Is there a method to get siri's speech's text

Tags: ios, sirikit

I wonder if there is a func to get **siri's speech's text**. But I counldn't find it.
Anyone can help? Thx in advance.

Comment: can i know in what situation you need the Siri's speech text?

Comment: Ummm. I just wonder if I could get string result from SiriKit.

Comment: I want to just say Hey siri ' thing i want to search for '. and i can pass this string to server which returns me a url which i want to open in a browser. Can it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method to get the siri's speech text. The `IntentHandler` will  return the processed information as an Intent object to your Extension.

Comment: Any update from apple on this. Can i get the text from siri now?